# How to get 5 volts from Lightning pinout?

Tags: usb, pinout, usb-host, iphone, lightning

How to make the Lightning port of iPhone output 5V power?

Comment: someone said connect the ID pin to the ground but didn't said which ID pins and I connected the ID pin but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there seems to be no simple way to accomplish this. To do this, you would need a (Apple approved) device that can identify itself to the Apple device before it will output 5V power on the Lightning bus.

For some more background, look up:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119707/how-much-power-can-be-drawn-from-the-lightning-connector-by-a-external-device

and

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_(connector)

---

**Additional information from the Wikipedia page**

*"Official Lightning connectors contain an authentication chip that made it difficult for third-party manufacturers to produce compatible accessories without being approved by Apple* ***however, the authentication scheme has been cracked"***

---